# How to refactor|rename a macro defined variable in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Using the f2 key (rename symbol) command in VS Code while over a variable name and renaming it, seems to work well for `int` or other in-memory variables, but when I do so with a value defined by a macro define statement, it renames all the references just fine, but fails to rename the actual macro define name. For example lets say I have the following code:

```c
#define FOO 1

int foo = FOO;
```

If I place my cursor over `FOO` in `#define FOO 1`, press f2, then type a new name (e.g. BAR), VS Code will confirm all the locations `FOO` was found and if I want to refactor them (as expected). I press Apply, but I end up with:

```c
#define FOO 1

int foo = BAR;
```

which isn't very helpful :D. Now I have a broken link and have to manually fix both.

The behavior is the same regardless if I have my cursor on the first (`#define FOO 1`) or second (`int foo = FOO`) `FOO`.

Comment: You could use [CTRL] + [F2] _Change all Occurrences_. It seems that it only works within the active document, not across the workspace, unlike [F2] _Rename Symbol_. For such a task, i usually use [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + [H].

Comment: Thanks. I guess that would be fine for smaller projects or ones with only a few references for FOO, but not ideal for other cases. Maybe this is just a limitation of VS Code or the C/C++ plugin?

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be the case. I've looked into the settings and searched via [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[P], only those two choices. Maybe further research reveals more. Btw. VSCode is a fine editor, i myself enjoy it pretty much to work with it, but i've never trusted 'any' IDE to resolve symbols (let alone to make changes). At the end, it's a text editor, therefore i am used to work with text only and 'search/replace' is the only tool i use.

Comment: Maybe there are other options (looking for a vim extension). The thing I liked most about IDE refactors like this was their ability to differentiate use cases (e.g. comments vs variable uses.) If I had an unfortunately named variable like `from` or some other commonly used grammatical word, I've done some nightmarish undo processes after batch replacing things.

Comment: I know what you mean. But 'most' of the time regex does wonders. Yes i agree, sometimes tedious but doable. If the symbol resolving does not work, i blame the editor, but if the regex approach does not work, i have to blame myself, which btw. is a good motivator.